# JQuery & CSS on-screen keyboard not functioning on a remake of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

EDIT - Here's what I have: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wZQjQy
 Here's the original: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMRLBN
(had to put it on codepen, somehow adding a snippet here doesn't link the css)

I basically copy-pasted a customized on-screen keyboard which worked flawlessly (mostly) but after putting it in a different HTML, it's not working anymore.

[keyboard](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery--net-5774) I copied

This is the keyboard, all I really did is replace the characters with Cyrillic and remove the caps, tab, shift and all the "on" spans, since all I really need are the buttons and letters, all capitalized. Now, this worked nicely on my previous build for a page, but the page was inherently flawed by my endless barrage of copy-pasted material and became unfixable at some point, so I started over.
Using some more copy-paste but with Bootstrap now, I built something at least a quarter percent better than my previous mess. But when I imported the on-screen keyboard from the last HTML file, it's now not showing any characters, basically just not working. I really don't know what's going on.

the CSS (I included this because maybe the text is actually being written but just not being shown due to a messy CSS?)

```
$(function() {
  var $write = $('#write'),
    shift = false,
    capslock = false;

  $('#keyboard li').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      character = $this.html(); // If it's a lowercase letter, nothing happens to this variable

    // Shift keys
    if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
      $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
      $('.symbol span').toggle();

      shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
      capslock = false;
      return false;
    }

    // Caps lock
    if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
      $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
      capslock = true;
      return false;
    }

    // Delete
    if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
      var html = $write.html();

      $write.html(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
      return false;
    }

    // Special characters
    if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
    if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
    if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
    if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";

    // Uppercase letter
    if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();

    // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
    if (shift === true) {
      $('.symbol span').toggle();
      if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');

      shift = false;
    }

    // Add the character
    $write.html($write.html() + character);
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.maincontainer {
  background-image: url(b.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: right;
}


/*head*/

.nav-text {
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
}

.row {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.back-button {
  height: 100%;
}

#backer {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}

.red {
  background-color: darkred;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
}

.uk-icon {
  color: white;
}


/*main*/


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#tabone {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

#tabtwo {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(80, 3, 3);
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: rgb(180, 15, 15);
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  background-color: white;
}

#London {
  text-align: center;
}

#searchbutton {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#write {
  width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Soyombo_red.svg/300px-Soyombo_red.svg.png) no-repeat scroll 50px 40px;
  background-size: 80PX;
  padding-left: 50px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10vh;
}

#London>.container-fluid>h3 {
  margin-top: 5%;
  font-size: 4vh;
}

#keyboard {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

#keyboard li {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 5%;
  padding: 0;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7PX;
  ;
}

#keyboard .delete {
  width: 120px;
}

.lastitem {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.on {
  display: none;
}

#keyboard li:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#container.ul {
  margin: auto;
  float: center;
}

#container-x {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Y/3/d/w/R/r/search-icon-white-hi.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 25%;
  background-position-y: 50%;
  background-position-x: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

  <title>
    Payment
  </title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-keyboard@latest/build/css/index.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- UIkit CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.3/css/uikit.min.css" />
  <!-- UIkit JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.3/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.3/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <!-- My CSS & JS-->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="container-fluid red">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-">
          <div class="back-button">
            <a id="backer" class="uk-button uk-button-default" href="#"><span uk-icon="icon:arrow-left;"></span><span class="nav-text">Эхлэх</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl">
          <div class="header">
            Тээврийн хэрэгслийн торгууль төлөх
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-">
          <div class="header">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="uk-container">
      <img style="width: auto;" src="images/logo.png">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="tab">
          <button uk-icon="bus" class="tablinks" id="tabone" onclick="openTab(event, 'London')"><img style="width: 8.7%; margin-right: 10px;" src="images/car.png">ТЭЭВРИЙН ХЭРЭГСЭЛ</button>
          <button class="tablinks" id="tabtwo" onclick="openTab(event, 'Paris')"><img style="width: 9.3%; margin-right: 10px" src="images/passport.png">ЖОЛООНЫ ҮНЭМЛЭХ</button>
        </div>
        <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <h3>АВТОМАШИНЫ УЛСЫН ДУГААР</h3>
            <div id="input_container">
              <input type="text" id="write" maxlength="7" placeholder="UBA 0000">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Хайх" id="searchbutton" class="uk-button uk-button-default" href="#"></input>
          </div>

          <div style="width:auto;margin: auto;" id="container">
            <ul style="display:table; width:100%;" id="keyboard">
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">1</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">2</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">3</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">4</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">5</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">6</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">7</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">8</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">9</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">0</span></li>
              <li class="delete"><span class="delete"><img style="width:50%"
                                                                src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/sympletts-part-1/128/backspace-256.png"></span></li>
              <br>
              <li class="letter">Ф</li>
              <li class="letter">Ц</li>
              <li class="letter">У</li>
              <li class="letter">Ж</li>
              <li class="letter">Э</li>
              <li class="letter">Н</li>
              <li class="letter">Г</li>
              <li class="letter">Ш</li>
              <li class="letter">Ү</li>
              <li class="letter">З</li>
              <li class="letter">К</li>
              <li class="letter">Ъ</li><br>
              <li class="letter">Й</li>
              <li class="letter">Ы</li>
              <li class="letter">Б</li>
              <li class="letter">Ө</li>
              <li class="letter">А</li>
              <li class="letter">Х</li>
              <li class="letter">Р</li>
              <li class="letter">О</li>
              <li class="letter">Л</li>
              <li class="letter">Д</li>
              <li class="letter">П</li><br>
              <li class="letter">Я</li>
              <li class="letter">Ч</li>
              <li class="letter">Е</li>
              <li class="letter">Ё</li>
              <li class="letter">С</li>
              <li class="letter">М</li>
              <li class="letter">И</li>
              <li class="letter">Т</li>
              <li class="letter">Ь</li>
              <li class="letter">В</li>
              <li class="letter">Ю</li>
            </ul>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Paris</h3>

      </div>
      <script>
        function openTab(evt, tabName) {
          var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
          tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
          for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
          }
          tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
          for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
          evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }
      </script>



    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

When I click on a li element from the keyboard, it's supposed to call that JS, making magic happen. It ain't doing nothing.
My best guess is the "tabs" not being active on form load, since the only real difference is I used bootstrap tabs on the last one but on this one I copied the W3 schools one.

Comment: can you give us live page which has the keyboard to check?

Comment: Do you mean the original template I used or the one malfunctioning?

Comment: no, your implementation, which has the error

Comment: see edit, unfortunately i somehow messed up the CSS linking so codepen will do

Comment: change your input to textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your input area with ID "write" into a textarea.

Replace this line:

```
<input type="text" required="" id="write" maxlength="7" placeholder="UBA 0000">
```

with this:

```
<textarea id="write" rows="6" cols="60" placeholder="UBA 0000"></textarea>
```

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/AlexWayhill/pen/VNVBGN) shows the changed code.